# How can I see source code of compiled dll classes

Tags: c#

There is a case. I have 4 compiled classes included in my ASP.net, (c#) project which as BO.dll (an application extension file) and BO (program debug database file) say for example of 1 class. I have no source for these classes. How can I amend source of this class or can see the complete class.? Any idea??
example:

```
using Ctrl;
```

its calling like.

```
List<CompanyLPO> list = qCtrl.GetCompanyLPOApprovals();
```

when I press F12 on GetCompanyLPOApprovals it taken me into the bellow.

```
public List<CompanyLPO> GetCompanyLPOApprovals();
```

now I want to see GetCompanyLPOApprovals() source. How can I??

Regards,

Raja

Comment: Please put all DLL in in one folder. if "GetCompanyLPOApprovals" implementation is exists in any of the DLL then it will automatically redirect to those DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler/features.aspx).

Comment: I used Telerik JustDecompiler. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can see DLL code using [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have downloaded the .NET Reflector & this [FileGenerator](http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/) plugin , If you do,

1. Open up the Reflector.exe
2. Go to View and click Add-Ins,
3. In the Add-Ins window click Add...,
4. Then find the dll you have downloaded FileGenerator.dll (witch came
   wth the FileGenerator plugin)
5. Then close the Add-Ins window.
6. Go to File and click Open and choose the dll that you want to
   decompile,
7. After you have opend it, it will appear in the tree view,
8. Go to Tools and click Generate Files (Crtl+Shift+G),
9. select the output directory and select appropriate settings as your
   wish,
10. Click generate files.

Reply if success

Answer (score 1):

you're talking about *decompiling*. **.NET Reflector** is the way for viewing your source code this way. but notice that, it will not perfectly be the original code, but the estimation of what it was like.

There's also another tool, named *dotPeek*. [HERE](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.NET Reflector`](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [`ReSharper.`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) Both of them are great and not just for decompiling an assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Debug and decompile inside Visual Studio [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this online tool [http://www.showmycode.com/[1](http://www.showmycode.com/)
easily I am able to find the code